# TextEdit with cursor but no keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a `TextEdit` with it's cursor moving and selectable text but no keyboard (like the calculator app).
I have tried a solution which hides the keyboard right after it appears. but that is really slow and it shows itself for a moment before dissapearing.

is there any better solution (android 5.0.1 and above) ?

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` (activity tag inside manifest) didn't work

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
et.setCursorVisible(true);
et.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

either.

thanks in advance

Comment: why do you want cursor if you dont want to enter any data ?

Comment: @SagarNayak i want some button insert text where the cursor is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add below code in your activity.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Like,

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" />
```

**Edit**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
</FrameLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchAutoCompleteTextView_feed"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

Use `FrameLayout` for request focus. This will not add focus to `EditText`

Comment: that's strange but the keyboard still shows up after adding this!

Comment: sorry this question is not related. but I have edited my manifest xml and the changes doesn't appear in app. what should I do ?

Comment: I think your answer is correct. but the problem is. I clean/rebuild/re-run the project and manifest won't change in the app sent to my phone.

Comment: Remove your `gen` & `bin` directory and build again.

Comment: @ChintanRathod Bhai group ma add kar ne Gujarati android developer ma or koi admin ne ke

Answer (score 1):

I use this method to hide keyboard in my Utils class:

```
public static void hideKeyboard(@NonNull Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    View f = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    if (null != f && null != f.getWindowToken() && EditText.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getClass()))
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(f.getWindowToken(), 0);
    else
        activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
}
```

Comment: how should I use it ?

Comment: declare it in your utils class or similar and call the method:

Class.hideKeyboard(getActivity()); (in Fragment)
or
Class.hideKeyboard(this); (in Activity)

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

in your manifest file for your activity.

Comment: I remember this and used it before. but now if I compile and run on my galaxy s6 the keyboard shows up even with this attribute set in my activity tag. and I can't understand why !